# Build gridgain on Windows?

Tags: java, scala, grid-computing, gridgain

I just git pull'ed from head.

```
mvn compile
```

works fine.

```
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building gridgain 6.1.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] gridgain-tools .................................... SUCCESS [  1.097 s]
[INFO] jdk8-backport ..................................... SUCCESS [  1.453 s]
[INFO] gridgain-core ..................................... SUCCESS [ 24.937 s]
[INFO] gridgain-extdata-p2p .............................. SUCCESS [  0.757 s]
[INFO] gridgain-extdata-uri .............................. SUCCESS [  0.458 s]
[INFO] gridgain-clients .................................. SUCCESS [  1.522 s]
[INFO] gridgain-scalar ................................... SUCCESS [ 49.385 s]
[INFO] gridgain-examples ................................. SUCCESS [ 23.718 s]
[INFO] gridgain-visor-console ............................ SUCCESS [ 24.935 s]
[INFO] gridgain-jdbc-driver .............................. SUCCESS [  0.765 s]
[INFO] gridgain .......................................... SUCCESS [  0.000 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:09 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-01T13:22:38-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 50M/246M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\apps\gridgain>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
```

But

```
mvn package
```

is pretty unhappy (here is an excerpt):

```
[WARNING] Try running the build up to the lifecycle phase "package"
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:aggregate-jar (aggregate) @ gridgain-tools ---
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-fml:jar:1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug
 logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xdoc:jar:1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debu
g logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml:jar:1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable deb
ug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-6 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, ena
ble debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for m
ore details
[WARNING] The POM for commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more
details
[WARNING] The POM for log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

[WARNING] The POM for com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.12.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging f
or more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.1.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug l
ogging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logg
ing for more details
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AggregatorJavadocJar
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1901)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:653)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:863)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:790)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:278)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:210)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:986)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:982)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:133)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:462)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
        ... 54 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] gridgain-tools .................................... FAILURE [  3.116 s]
[INFO] jdk8-backport ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] gridgain-core ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] gridgain-extdata-p2p .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] gridgain-extdata-uri .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] gridgain-clients .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] gridgain-scalar ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] gridgain-examples ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] gridgain-visor-console ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] gridgain-jdbc-driver .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] gridgain .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Let me try to reproduce internally and I will post my findings here.

Comment: Please run with Maven debug options and add relative information here.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to run `mvn package` on Windows and it works for me. Looks like there is some issue with resolving transitive dependencies of JavaDoc plugin. Please try running Maven with debug options (`-X` and `-e`).